# Relative and absolute position not working on a fortawesome icon

Tags: html, css

I used a diamond symbol in fort awesome icon and if i target the i tag in css, the icon is getting highlighted (screen shot attached) but relative and absolute positioning not working. (source code also attached.) [screen shot of the diamond affected by targeting the i tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWC02.jpg)

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"><i class="fa fa-diamond" style="color:red"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Diamond</div>
```

**CSS**

```
i { 
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Is the parent div positioned?

Comment: when I tested it with my local project it works. You need to show non-working jsfiddle.

Comment: works for me, share your code please!

Comment: I did not position the parent element, it worked after positioning that. Thank you guys

Comment: You have not provided enough code (or a reproducible test case) for your question to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this in CSS

```
#test{position: relative;)
```

Also, just fyi, it's fontAwesome :)

Comment: This is not the reason why the element is not obeying valid, top and right CSS rules. (If there is no positioned ancestor and of `position: absolute` element, it will become absolutely positioned to the browser window).

Comment: Hi Adam, do you know what the reason is?

Comment: No, the code in the original question doesn't reproduce the issue, all I know is that the code in this answer doesn't solve it.

Comment: Absolute positioning is not a complex property, the reason is most likely a (non-relatively positioned parent) as well as a relatively positioned parent without the intention of doing so. Setting the immediate parent to relative position would most likely solve the issue. Otherwise, the issue might be a missing semicolon or brackets, which is not visible in this case.

Comment: Look at the screenshot in the link in the OPs question - the element in question isn't moved (and therefore not being absolutely positioned) so it's most likely, as you say, a missing semicolon/bracket which wasn't posted in the question, and not due to a parent that wasn't positioned.

Answer (score 0):

First, the most common name for this library is "FontAwesome" rather than "FortAwesome".

Regarding your questions, here you can see a fiddle that works just fine with the code you provided.

```css
i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: 30px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="test"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Diamond</div>
```

Please iterate on this example to reproduce your issue.